# React with emojis missing ID from message

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

I'm trying to build a system where a webhook posts a message from a Google Sheet, then my Bot reacts to the message with the emojis contained therein. I've got the the webhook posting the messages just fine and I have the Bot reacting to normal messages correctly. I can't get the two to work together, though. I suspect the problem is that the emojis as delivered by the webhook are incomplete (`:emoji:`, instead of `<:emoji:1234567890:>`). I am not aware of any way to get the ID# from the emoji string, or to pull the properly formatted emojis from the message object. Is there a way to do either of these or make this work by some other means? Here's what I have:

```js
const emojiRegex = require('emoji-regex/RGI_Emoji.js');

client.on('message', message => {
    const re = emojiRegex();
    let match;
    let emojis = [];
    while ((match = re.exec(message.content)) != null) {
        emojis.push(match[0]);
      }
    console.log(emojis);
    if (emojis) {
        emojis.forEach( e => {
            message.react(e);
        })
    }
});
```

Or, alternatively:

```js
emojis = message.content.match(/:.+?:/g);
```

`message.guild.emojis` doesn't seem to do what I'm hoping.

Thank you for any help you can offer.

---

Edit: I've now also tried the following with no success:

```js
client.on('message', message => {
    let emojis = [];
    let e1 = [];
    let e2 = [];

    e1 = message.content.match(/:.+?:/g);
    console.log(e1);
    if (e1) { 
        e1.forEach( e => {
            e2.push(e.match(/[a-zA-Z0-9_]+/g).toString());
        })
    }
    console.log(e2);
    if (e2) {
        e2.forEach( e => {
            emojis.push(client.emojis.cache.find(emoji => emoji.name === e));
        })
    }
    console.log(emojis);
    if (emojis) {
        emojis.forEach( e => {
            message.react(e);
        })
    }
});
```

Comment: maybe an example of what the webhook sends into your channel would be helpful.

Comment: An example of the sort of message the webhook sends is: 
**Match 25:** 
:flags:  King of Pain - The Police - https://youtu.be/SZlRX03BzeA
 vs.
:accordion: Another One Rides the Bus - Weird Al Yankovic - https://youtu.be/79QxturUolo

Answer (score 1):

This is an incomplete solution, as it works less than half the time. I presume this is because `emoji-name-map` has an incomplete list of possible names for unicode emojis. If you know of a better solution, I'm eager to hear it.

```js
client.on('message', message => {

    const enm = require("emoji-name-map");
    const one = enm.get('one');
    const two = enm.get('two');

    let e1 = [];
    let e2 = [];

    e1 = message.content.match(/:.+?:/g);
    console.log(e1);
    if (e1) { 
        e1.forEach( e => {
            e2.push( {name: e.match(/[a-zA-Z0-9_]+/g).toString(), id: null, unicode: null} );
        })
    }
    console.log(e2);
    if (e2) {
        e2.forEach( e => {
            try {
                e.id = client.emojis.cache.find(emoji => emoji.name === e.name);
            } catch (err) {
                console.log(err);
            };
            try {
                e.unicode = enm.get(e.name);
            } catch (err) {
                console.log(err);
            }
        })
    }
    console.log(e2);
    if (e2) {
        let i = 0;
        e2.forEach( e => {
            if (typeof e.id != 'undefined') {
                message.react(e.id);
            } else if (typeof e.unicode != 'undefined' ) {
                message.react(e.unicode);
            } else { message.react( i === 0 ? one : two ) };
            i++;
        })
    }
});
```